# Let $S=\{a,b\}$. Give the tables for all possible binary operations on $S$. (There are 16).

Tags: abstract-algebra

I wasn't quite sure how to get started on this, but I tried by letting $a$ be an identity and then letting $b$ be an identity and ended up with four tables like this (I'm not sure how to make it look nice here):

$*|a$ $b$

$a|$$a$ $b$

$b$|$b$ $a$

where $b*b=a$ and another where $b*b=b$ (with similar cases for the ones where $b$ is the identity). I'm not sure how I'm supposed to get 16 of these though.

Comment: Not all operations need to have an identity. Note that the operation is uniquely determined by such a table and that any table gives a valid operation.

Comment: Okay, so I could have a set of tables where there are no identities and all of the outputs are arbitrarily defined?

Comment: Yes, there are no requirements on the operation

Comment: Ah, this problem requires less thought than I thought then.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

[image]

${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$

Comment: @Babak well done, 1 up from me!

Comment: Well done, indeed! +1